# PyTest for running tests on multiple CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, validation, pytest

I want to load multiple CSV files and run the same set of tests with pytest for each of them individually. Can anyone help me how to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

I tried to use a for loop, but that didn't work as intended.

```
import pandas as pd

file_names = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']

class TestCSV:
    def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
        self.data = pd.DataFrame

    def test_na():
        for col in self.data.columns:
           assert self.data[col].isna().sum() == 0


for file in file_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    tests = TestCSV(df)
```

Comment: Hey, please edit your question to include a reproducible example, code, problem and if possible. Your post does not qualify as a clear question

Comment: I added a code example

Comment: You can [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/parametrize.html) your testclass, with the list of filenames.
Then pytest will run the testclass once for every file.

Comment: Spotted a mistake. It should be `self.data = data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that you want each set of `data[col]` to be a separate test case. If that is true, here is one way to approach this test:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import pytest


def generate_data(file_names):
    for file_name in file_names:
        data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        for col_number, col in enumerate(data.columns):
            yield pytest.param(data[col], id=f"file: {file_name}, col: {col_number}")


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "data_col",
    generate_data(["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]),
)
def test_na(data_col):
    assert data_col.isna().sum() == 0
```

Output:

```
$ pytest -v
...
test_na.py::test_na[file: file1.csv, col: 0] PASSED
test_na.py::test_na[file: file1.csv, col: 1] PASSED
test_na.py::test_na[file: file2.csv, col: 0] PASSED
test_na.py::test_na[file: file2.csv, col: 1] PASSED
```

Notes

- The `generate_data()` function will generate every columns in every files
- The `pytest.param()` provide a test case ID, which is useful to identify which file, which column failed
- I don't know how to generate the column number, so I use the `enumerate()` function for that purpose

Comment: @Niels remember to close the question by accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following script as `something.py` and run it from the terminal using `pytest`:

```
import pytest
import pandas as pd

fileNames = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']  # List of CSV file names

@pytest.fixture(params=fileNames)
def csvFile(request):
    df = pd.read_csv(request.param)  # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
    return df  # Return the DataFrame as the fixture value

class TestCSV:
    def testNaValues(self, csvFile):
        for col in csvFile.columns:
            assert csvFile[col].isna().sum() == 0  # Assert that there are no NaN values in the current column
```

The result for me are like that, I used files with no NaNs:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.13, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/tinod/Schreibtisch/Python_projects/Stack
plugins: anyio-3.5.0
collected 2 items                                                              

something.py ..                                                                [100%]

============================== 2 passed in 0.32s ===============================
```

Think about using `os.listdir()` to automatically get all `.csv` files you have in a directory

*Also very important!*: remember to use the correct parameters for the `pd.read_csv` function. This includes what the `sep` is, as it is typically a comma